# How to get an object's attribute value from an array of objects PHP

Tags: php

my problem is in PHP..
I have an object location with attributes name,date,address and get and set methods...
    class location{
        public $name;
        public $date;
        public $address;
        public function set_name($myname){
            $this->name=$myname;
        }
        public function get_name(){
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
Then i created an array `$locations_array=array();`

i also created an instance of the class location:

```
$my_loc=new location;
$my_loc->set_name("africa");
$locations_array[0]=$my_loc;
echo $locations_array[0]->get_name();
```

when i try to echo the name of the object $my_loc..there's an error..how can i remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in an interactive PHP shell and everything worked fine. It must be some kind of error specific to your computer, either that or a typo.

And you might want to reconsider even the existence of the set_name and get_name functions if the name property is public anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much..i think i made a small error...i forgot to add the "$" before a variable..that's why it wasn't getting the data...

Comment: Yeah, I've made errors like that all the time. No worries. It really stinks when you're missing one semicolon in like a hundred lines of code. XD